# Async FileStream Writes "NUL" into file

Tags: c#, .net

I am using this code to write asynchronously to a file

```
    public static void AsyncWrite(string file, string text)
    {
        try
        {
            byte[] data = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(text);                

            using ( FileStream fs = new FileStream(file, FileMode.Create,
                FileAccess.Write, FileShare.Read, 1, true))                                         
                    fs.BeginWrite(data, 0, data.Length, null, null);
        }            
        catch
        {

        }            
    }
```

For some reason, from time to time, rather than writing text into the file as expected, Notepad++ shows the following ouput :

[image]

Comment: Can you show a Hex dump of the result?

Comment: Not Sure to know how to do that...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`BeginWrite` is asynchronous, so it might well happen that the stream is closed through the `using` statement while other things are happening.

I'd not use `using` when doing asynchronous writing. Instead I'd create a proper callback method and close the stream there. This would also give you the chance to call `EndWrite` as recommended.

Comment: My eyes are grateful to you. I was turning epileptic with all these NULL blinking lines on my log windows. Smart answer it did'nt occur tome me. Many thanks